# Folder permission ASP.NET site online

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, permissions

I'm uploading files into a folder. It works as it should when I run the solution locally, but when I've uploaded the site to the web server using "copy website", - I can no longer upload files to the folder.

Can I change the permissions somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends is the user that is trying to upload the file(s) into that directory on the server have permissions to that folder on the server, eg: read/write, ect... Also is the user that will be using that program on the server is running the application as themselves or as the IIS User account, or some other dedicated account?

**Update:**

Since you are doing it through the VPN, try terminal serving to that server and if you have personally permissions to make this change as in give permissions then do it yourself or ask the admins to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the folder you are uploading your files into and the account you have configured the web server to execute your application under, there might be different ways to achieve that. But basically you should rant write access to this account to the given folder you are saving the uploaded files into. But if you use some of the special ASP.NET folders such as `App_Data` for example to store the uploaded files, the account should already have write permission to that folder. And if you have uploaded your site to some hosting company that don't provide you the possibility to change permissions on the different folders that are part of your website you might need to contact the support so that they perform he necessary modifications that you need.

Comment: Can this be done using VS? I'm uploading the site using VPN connection to server, and have only done this thing with folders using FTP-clients before...

Comment: @user1121487, of course that it can't be done using VS. VS is not a magic tool that can grant permissions to folders on remote servers. That's what administrators do. Well, if you already have an administrator account for the remote server you could do that yourself. If not, contact the administrators.